# Prove that limit of $ne^{-an}$ as $n$ goes to infinity equals $0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Somehow I learnt that the limit of $ne^{-an}$ (for $a > 0$) is $0$ as $n$ goes to infinity. I was trying to convert the expression to the form $\frac{e^{-an}}{\frac{1}{n}}$ and then use the L'Hôpital's rule but then I am getting the symbol $0\cdot \infty$ over and over again. How can prove it?

Comment: What about $\frac{n}{e^{an}}$ instead?

Comment: @AndréNicolas, oh, I didn't think about just simplifying this. It's so obvious. Thank you!

Comment: @LiveForever, it was a mistake (I didn't noticed 'without'), already fixed it.

Comment: @wizdoz: You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The original post had a tag "No L'Hospital's Rule."  The ensuing presentation was written under that constraint.

In [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589429/how-to-prove-that-logxx-when-x1/1590263#1590263), I showed using only (i) the limit definition of the exponential function and Bernoulli's Inequality that the exponential function satisfies the inequality

$$e^x\ge \left(1+\frac xn\right)^n$$

for $x>-n$.  We can set $n=2$ and assert that for $x>-2$,

$$e^x\ge 1+x+\frac14 x^2$$

Then, we have

$$\begin{align}
0&< ne^{-an}\\\\
&=\frac{n}{e^{an}}\\\\
&\le\frac{n}{1+an+\frac14 (an)^2}
\end{align}$$

whereupon applying the squeeze theorem yield the expected limit!